# Is there a "readable" map of the Warhammer world?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

I found a map of the Old World of *Warhammer* but is is really blurry.

Was wondering if there is a much better resolution of this map where the entire world is shown in detail?

The entire map of the Empire, Bretton, wood elves (?), Border princess kingdoms, Kislev is a huge smudge. So is Ulthuan and countless other places.

[image: Warhammer World]

Comment: [Here's a new one](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/FW-oCAhXwAEgDFm?format=jpg&name=large)

Answer (score 4):

Here is map of the *Warhammer* world in Google Maps format available [here at Gitzman's Gallery](http://www.gitzmansgallery.com/shdmotwow.html). I am unsure what exact period it depicts, but consider it a very convenient tool for RPG session planning.

Comment: great find. +1 but im looking for the entire thing. Lustria, dark elves land, Ulthuan, Ind, Nippon, Cathay, Ogre kingdoms, etc.

Comment: Ah, my bad then. ;)
I wish good luck in finding in this case(actually I wouldn't mind seeing one too...).

Comment: "what exact period it depicts" : "2522nd year of Sigmar's Glorious Empire"

Answer (score 4):

With the latest *Total War: Warhammer III* release, we now have this (very readable, but geographically compressed) map at 1920x1493 from the game's Twitter account:

[image: Warhammer world map]

---

The largest I can find with a basic image search is 1434x975:

[image: Warhammer World Map]

There's also a sharpened version on the [Warhammer Fandom Wiki](https://warhammerfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/File:Warhammer_olde_world_map.jpg). I'm not sure where it comes from originally.

If you want more detail you'll need to piece it together from larger maps of smaller areas. There may be something available for the new *Total War: Warhammer III* game.

Your original appears to be this with the campaign maps from *Total War: Warhammer II* overlaid.

Comment: Rewording previous comments, because I was getting unnecessarily combative, sorry: It would be good to include a credit for this image, if you know one. Even if it's copied around a lot, it will still be subject to copyright, and it's good to give credit where it's due. If you don't know its licensing status, but think it qualifies for the "fair use exemption" in the current context, saying so clarifies that copying it to other contexts might not be.

Comment: I cannot determine the original source. It appears ubiquitous on the official TW:Warhammer forums, so presumably GW and CA (the likely rights holders) have no objections to its use.